# Using CF 9 Script how do I upload a file and rename at the same time?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Using CF 9 Script how do I upload a file and rename at the same time?

Below is an examples of what I have so far it works but I cannot get the file extension for the image upload dynamically.

```
local.results=fileUpload("D:\wwwroot\imageStore\#local.hash#.#cffile.serverFileExt#","image","","makeUnique");
```

cffile.serverFileExt = error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serverFileExt value isn't available until after the upload completes. You would need to upload the file and then get the server file extension from the results structure.

Comment: then how do I do a rename because fileRename no longer seems to be in CF9 script

Answer (score 2):

You can use fileMove to rename in script after the file has uploaded.

[fileMove](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d9d.html)